# Specific children update triggers parent method for all children instead

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am making an application in vue.js that do some heavy duty calculation of an excel document given by a user.I need to check the validity of a client based on some filter provided by the user.
The problem that i have right now is that for some reason, when a children component is updated, the parent method `calculateModel(modele)` is recalled when it shouldn't . This freezes The UI due to the heavy calculation and is unecessary. This is mainly due to the fact that the data of those component are binded to that method. So when a children is updated it recalls the method for every children

I tried to do this with computed property but it doesn't seem to work either.
My first guess would be to bind the data to a variable but the problem is that those variable should be created dynamically because every file has a different number of vehicule and model

Here is my parent calculatedModel Method

```
     calculateModel(modele) {
                console.log('in calculateModel'); // called 20 time on children update when it shoudn't
                let dataModele = [];
                let distance = [];
                let colonneModele = this.documentHeader['12'];

                for (let i = 0; i < this.grid.data.length; i++) {
                    if (this.grid.data[i][colonneModele] === modele) {
                        dataModele.push(this.grid.data[i]);
                        distance.push(this.distance[i])
                    }
                }
                return [dataModele, distance];
            }
```

Here is the template of my parent component creating the problem

```
<div v-for="modele in valueModele" class="row mt-4 w-100 fmt-card">
 <option-personnalise-form v-if="checkifInFilter(modele)" 
   @calculatedRP="onCalculatedRP"
   :options-modele="optionsModele" :year="optionYear"
   :title="modele.name" :data="calculateModel(modele.name)"
   :filter-marque="valueMarque" :documentHeader="documentHeader"
   :allDistance="distance"
   :filter-modele="valueModele">
  </option-personnalise-form>
</div>
```

Here how the application should work. The parent component read the document. After it dispatches the data to every children component base on the model of a car. So if we have 3 Civic, and 5 Accord, it will give only the civic data to one chidlren and the Accord data to the other one. When the Accord Children is updated. The data of those children should be static from there

Comment: Function calls in bindings will generally be called on every update. You should probably make a `computed` that you would bind like `:data=modelData[modele.name]`.

Comment: I think it would help if you'd add the `key` attribute to each item from your `v-for` loop. This way vue will differentiate between the items and will avoid unnecessary re-renders.